# Generate different artifactId when publish library in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am publish library in kotlin multiplatform. I used this command `./gradlew clean assemble publish` my three package is generated. I given the name `var libraryArtifactId = "kmm-module"` but I don't understand why other name is coming from.

1st package name is `com.vivek.kmm-module`

2nd package name is `com.vivek.kotlinproject-android-debug`

3rd package name is `com.vivek.kotlinproject-android`

I understand 1st package name, but I am not understanding where the 2nd and 3rd artificatId coming from?

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.21"
    id("com.android.library")
    id("maven-publish")
}

val libraryVersion = "0.0.1"
var libraryGroup = "com.vivek"
var libraryArtifactId = "kmm-module"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val androidMain by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 21
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
    }
    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage") compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        group = libraryGroup
        publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
            groupId = libraryGroup
            artifactId = libraryArtifactId
            version = libraryVersion
        }

        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/vivek-modi/kotlinmultiplatfromproject")
                credentials {
                    username = (System.getenv("GITHUB_USER") ?: project.properties["GITHUB_USER"]).toString()
                    password = (System.getenv("GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN") ?: project.properties["GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"]).toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding my [github repository](https://github.com/vivek-modi/KotlinMultiplatfromProject). I used github packages for publishing library. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can remove this line to avoid the android artifact.

```
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
    }
```

Comment: The issue is the wrong artifact name when publishing the Android artifact